# Project Structure for unit testing (qtest) when using target_sources() command in sub directory

Tags: c++, cmake, project-structure, ctest, qtestlib

First of all, I know there are very similar questions in this forum. However, none really answer my specific case.
I have the following project structure:

```
|---Project_Root
    |---CMakeLists.txt
    |---build
    |---src
    |   |---CMakeLists.txt
    |   |---many .cpp and .h files in multiple subfolders with a different CMakeLists.txt 
    |---tests
    |   |---CMakeLists.txt
    |   |---many .cpp files
```

In the Project_Root/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(SRC_DIR src)

project(
        Project
        LANGUAGES CXX
        )

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SRC_DIR})
add_subdirectory(${SRC_DIR})
```

In the src folder and subfolder CMakeLists.txt files:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(SRC_FILES
    Source1.cpp
    )

set(HEADER_FILES
    Source1.hpp
    )
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SRC_FILES}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${HEADER_FILES}
        )
```

Now in the tests subfolder:

```
project(Test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
enable_testing()

add_executable(Test tst_test.cpp)
add_test(NAME Test COMMAND Test)

target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE Qt5::Test)
```

In the above CMakeLists.txt I want to include the main project as a static library. I can, for example, add a new library target (say `Project_Lib`) in the root CMakeLists.txt and use once again the command:

```
target_sources(Project_Lib
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SRC_FILES}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${HEADER_FILES}
        )
```

in all the subfolders.
**But is there a more elegant way of doing it without having to modify all the CMakeLists.txt in the subfolders**? For example, is there way to extract the source files from the `Project` target, so that it can be reused to make the `Project_Lib` target?

Comment: `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SRC_FILES}` makes no sense 1. it appends `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to only first of the files and 2. all files are relative to CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR anyway.

Comment: Why not build all of your sources in `src` into a static library instead, then link that library to both `Project` and `Test` executables? Seems to me that would be the easiest change, requiring only a couple extra lines of CMake code...

Comment: @KamilCuk without ``` ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SRC_FILES}``` I get the following error in my root CMakeLists.txt : ```Cannot find source file:A.hpp
Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx``` where ```A.hpp``` in one of the subfolders of ```src``` folder. If I add ```{CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SRC_FILES}```, I dont get this error

Comment: @squareskittles  your idea is very intriguing but I dont fully understand it. If I build a static library in ```src``` what will I link it again in ```Project``` target as there won't be any source files outside ```src```.

Comment: Doesn't your `Project` executable target have a `main` function (perhaps, inside a `main.cpp` or similar)? Just exclude this one file from the static library, and use it as the only source file in the `Project` executable.

Comment: Yeah sure that would work thanks. But it there a way without having to modify Cmakelists.txt of all the subfolders (in order change the target name in target_sources command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described, you can make a new static library target `Project_Lib`. Take advantage of the fact that you *parameterized* the target name by using the project name (`${PROJECT_NAME}`), so you actually don't have to change all of the CMakeLists.txt files in the subfolders. Just change the project name.

As I commented, simply **exclude** the `main.cpp` file from the static library, and add it to a separate executable target instead.

In Project_Root/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(SRC_DIR src)

# Change the project name, as now the static library is the primary target.
project(
        Project_Lib
        LANGUAGES CXX
        )

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Create the static library target, whose sources are populated in subdirectories.
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SRC_DIR})
# The only modification necessary in the subdirectories is to *exclude* the 
# main.cpp file from the target_sources for the static library.
add_subdirectory(${SRC_DIR})

# Add *only* the main.cpp file to the executable target.
add_executable(Project_Exe src/main.cpp)
# Link the static library target to the executable.
target_link_libraries(Project_Exe PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

In tests/CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
# Link the static library to your Test executable also.
target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE Project_Lib Qt5::Test)
```